# How to pulse generator block generate a pulse 40khz?

Tags: matlab, simulink, pulse

I tried to generate a 40khz pulse to the GPIO pin of my ultrasonic sensor in raspberry pi. I used the pulse generator instrumentation, but the pulse is not accurate: the oscilloscope displays only 10khz.

I modified configuration parameters:

```
fixed-step
sample time is auto/1e-08
solver is auto/discrete
```

I also have tried various ways to create a square pulse: function sign(sin(2*pi*40000t)), PLL block, repeating sequence, signal generator combined with sum, compare to zero, etc.
All of these display correctly on the scope, but do not deploy accurately.

I doubted the raspberry pulse generatior, so I used python to drive the GPIO pin; results are very accurate. I worry that the Simulink complier doesn't properly support raspberry or the sample time.

Any suggestions?

This is the model I used to generate 40khz pulse.

[image]

with period is 0.000025s,pulse width 50%, Solver type is fixed-step.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QP9Hx.png]

The oscilloscope display as the following figure:

Comment: Cleaned up wording.

Comment: I couldn't see the oscilloscope figure. Is it a pulse as expected, but with the period out by a factor of x4? If so have you tried setting the period to 160kHz to see if that results in 40kHz in hardware? This isn't a solution but would help with trouble shooting.

Comment: What do you mean by `sample time is auto/1e-08`? Does that imply that your model step function runs with 100 MHz? And the Raspberry Pi itself even has a much higher clocking frequency?